# class Cast problem in RestTemplateBuilder with SpringBoot 2.15

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have this piece of code in my program:

```
this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

but I have this compilation error

```
Cannot resolve method 'requestFactory(org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)'
```

Even the method expects this:

```
 public RestTemplateBuilder requestFactory(Class<? extends ClientHttpRequestFactory> requestFactory)
```

and the class `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory implements ClientHttpRequestFactory, DisposableBean`

Comment: The parameter is expected to be the `Class` object of the factory. Not the instance of the factory as you're trying to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
restTemplatebuilder.requestFactory(() -> { return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);});
```